# How to create email proxy server using php

Tags: php, smtp

I want to create a system, where an email is sent to me using smtp and i perform all the validation and some manipulations in HTML. and then send it using SMTP.

Currently i have some applications which are using SMTP as email sender, i want to create a simple layer in between them so that all the emails are sent from this filter, so that i can edit HTML source code and add some tracking links or check weather to send this email or not, depending on the spam and other filters.

Comment: That's a nice plan. What have you tried to do it?

Comment: How is the initial email to be sent?

Comment: @DocRattie i want to write an filter for my different services, and add some tracking codes to the HTML sent via my existing email services.

Comment: @Deejay that says nothing about what you tried. Without any code or information about it, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) is a great PHP framework for sending emails, its supposedly very difficult to send emails from within PHP its self using the mail() function.

Are you trying to import an email sent from a specific address to you, extract data from that email and then forward the information on? Can we get an example of the email you are trying to extract/manipulate? I feel some more information on the task at hand would make this easier!

**EDIT**

So if understand correctly you want to program an application that all your other applications interface with and send emails from this new application?

If so there is lots of ways you could do this, I'm not aware of any github solutions (Correct me if I'm wrong) & I don't think any sort of SMTP service offers what you are asking (HTML changing being the big problem I'd imagine).

So what you could do is write an application with an API (referring which application sent the request, desired recipient, email template to use ETC) with all of your different settings/spam filter restrictions stored in database. You could then keep your emails all in a folder within the new application and when you amend them they get sent out.

Another solution would be to create a folder that contained all of the email templates, then create system links (securing X,Y&Z attack vectors) to your different PHP projects which depend on these email templates and do per application filtering (Spam/HTML Changes).

Comment: It's very easy to send simple text emails with Php's native mail() function.  You just have to code against mail injection.

Comment: So you want to create an email template repository ?

Comment: no @Danturnip i simpy want to create a system where i can manipulate emails before it is send out.

Comment: @Danturnip Thanks, i can go with API method, but the problem is i will have to make change in all other applications, since they are using the SMTP protocol, and i just want to change the smtp addres to my filter and then that filter sends email automatically...

Comment: The methods I have described above are the methods I would use / know, I don't think any sort of SMTP service offers what you are asking (HTML changing being the big problem I'd imagine), but hey there is a market for you to move into ;) If these answer above is correct please mark it that way!